# ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor Create Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, reporting

I have ASP.Net MVC3 project with Razor template, and I need to make a reporting tool for summary reports and detailed reports.

I do not know how to create such reports in MVC3. Could anyone give me an example for creating these reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a built-in control for reports, there is however an HTML helper for displaying charts. Please see example [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=597)

SSRS reports are not supported by default in MVC 3, therefore you need to use a report viewer control. Article explaning how to do this can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajoshi/archive/2010/06/16/asp-net-mvc-handling-ssrs-reports-with-reportviewer-part-i.aspx)

Comment: i already have the report using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and now i want to view all those report in my MVC 3 Project.

Comment: thanks, i've done my report and its like you said that i must use report viewer control.

Answer (score 0):

first, i must configure the dataset in my project. because i use storedprocedure, so i must add new table adapter in my dataset.

then i add new item (for the report file) in my project and design the report using report wizard.

after that, for showing the report in my project, i add new web form and in my web form, drag the report viewer and script manager. choose the design view to set up the report.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" SizeToReportContent="true" 
        Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\rptbooking.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="rptBatchClose.RDYGetawayDataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

this is the simple way to make SSRS report in my MVC3 Project.